# Script on python for Zabbix LLD discovery rule

Tags: python, zabbix

I need to write a python script to monitor the change of sudoers files. I want to implement this in Zabbix using the LLD Discovery rule. As I understand it, I need to have data in JSON at the output. Since I am just learning how to write scripts I ran into a problem. I can't figure out how to implement this. I ask for help. Here is my script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

file_path = ["/etc/sudoers",
"/etc/sudoers.d/file1",
"/etc/sudoers.d/file2"]
import os.path
import json
for i in file_path:
        a = os.path.isfile(i)
        if a == True:
            print(i)
```

Comment: What does the JSON file need to look like?

Comment: Can you post a sample of the expected `JSON` output? Python has a `json` module in the standard library.

Answer (score 0):

JSON is a format very similar to a Python dict.
My suggestion would be to create a Python dict that represents the data you would like to have in JSON format.
Then, take that dict object and return it as a JSON string for whatever you need. Here's an example:

```
file_path = ['/etc/sudoers', '/etc/sudoers.d/file1', '/etc/sudoers.d/file2']
import os.path
import json
json_data = {}
for path in file_path:
    json_data[path] = os.path.isfile(path)

>>> json.dumps(json_data)
'{"/etc/sudoers": false, "/etc/sudoers.d/file1": false, "/etc/sudoers.d/file2": false}'
```

Comment: I'm need output like this {
        "data":[

            { "{#FILE_PATH}":"/etc/sudoers"  },
            { "{#FILE_PATH}":"/etc/sudoers.d/file1"  },
            { "{#FILE_PATH}":"/etc/sudoers.d/file2"  }
            
            ]
}

Comment: The idea is for zabbix to check only those files that exist. For this, I wrote the condition if a == True: print (i) so that it only prints the files that exist.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone will come in handy

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import json
import os.path
list_a = ["/etc/sudoers",
"/etc/sudoers.d/file1",
"/etc/sudoers.d/file2"]
list_b = []

for a in list_a:
        b = os.path.isfile(a)
        if b == True:
            dict_files = {}
            dict_files["#FILE_PATH"] = (a)
            list_b.append(dict_files)
            z = json.dumps(list_b)

print(z)
```

Thx for help all. And thx for help my colleague Alex!